# How do I make captured large fish swim around in an area filled with water in Starbound?

Tags: starbound

I captured some large fish and placed them in a pet tether in a "tank" full of water. The fish just swims around at ground level where the tether is placed though. Is there some way to release it without the tether? I'm trying to make an aquarium.